# Flutter keeping getx service presistant even if app is killed

Tags: flutter, dart, webrtc, flutter-getx, flutter-webrtc

I have app when I have initiated a services, now when is in foreground or background things are working, but when app is terminated or killed, the getx service take time to initialise, and due to which my user are not getting time to check thing, example if i call in flutter and app is killed, i get notification for calling when I click answer button it's takes time to open app then register service and all.
Is there any way to keep getx service be there even after app is closed.

I have tried to call the service before calling the runApp function in main.dart still its not giving proper output

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We cannot share code, as per company policies.